# From Tallinn harbour to the main bus station

Tags: public-transport, buses, taxis, tallinn

From **Tallinn harbour** it's a relatively long way to the **main bus station** (*Tallinna bussijaam*; [Lastekodu 46](http://goo.gl/maps/2uso)). From terminal A (e.g. Viking Line, Eckerö Line) it's a [3.1 km (~40 min)](http://goo.gl/maps/10ps) and from terminal D (Tallink) [2.3 km (~30 min)](http://goo.gl/maps/UFlE) walk, according to Google Maps.

Is there a **quick & convenient way to make the trip using some form of public transport**? Or would a **taxi** be significantly handier (yet not much more expensive)?

I couldn't find a good online journey planner for Tallinn public transport.

(Bonus question: If taxi is your recommendation, and you know Tallinn intimately, could you mention some taxi companies to prefer / avoid? To my knowledge price and reliability can vary a lot, and it's worthwhile to be picky at a taxi stand.)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Tallinn route planner](http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/#tallinna-linn/map/en), [bus line 2](http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/#bus/2/a-b/map/en) runs between Harbour terminals A and D (Reisisadam) and Mõigu, via the bus station (Autobussijaam) and the airport (Lennujaam). There are roughly 2 buses per hour on weekdays, 3 on weekends. The trip takes roughly 10 minutes between terminal D and the bus station, 3 minutes between terminals A and D, and another 7 minutes between the bus station and the airport. You can buy tickets from the driver, but they're a little cheaper from a kiosk.

Wikitravel has [recommendations about taxis](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tallinn#By_taxi).

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the route planner is much more useful than what I thought after a quick look. The [fare for single ticket](http://www.tallinn.ee/eng/Fares-and-tickets-in-Tallinn-01.01.2011) seems to be 1.60 € from driver and 1 € from "trade outlets".

Answer (score 2):

All that I remember is that the main bus station (Where I arrived) had free wifi, so I checked google maps to the old district, decided it was too far (1 hour) to walk - was meeting people, so I caught a cab.  The trick was that he couldn't actually drive into the old town, so had to drop me off at the edge.

As you've probably found, it's [about a 30 min walk to the bus station](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=ferry%20terminal,%20tallinn&daddr=bus%20station,%20tallinn&hl=en&sll=59.43528,24.76937&sspn=0.018811,0.055747&geocode=FUYGiwMdF-l5ASEBXEAQrEIaXynzMGZEXZOSRjEBXEAQrEIaXw;FcnKigMdSAd6ASFclPn1tPlsYiltAfJnqJSSRjFclPn1tPlsYg&t=v&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ltm&z=15&start=0) from the ferry terminals.

The [tourism website](http://www.tourism.tallinn.ee/eng/postoffice/faq) states that it's about 6 Euros from the Harbour to the Center of Town, so that should  give you a rough idea.  But again, if you're staying in the old town, they can only drop you at the old gates, anyway.

According to [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tallinn#By_taxi), there are certainly dodgy companies that will prey on unsuspecting tourists.  They have a list there of reputable companies to use.  Also be aware that they may have an entrance fee to get into the terminal area, so you could walk to just outside and get one from there.  It's about a 5 min walk, from memory.  Or ask the approximate rate before getting in, of course.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, though some bits ("But again, if you're staying in the old town, ...") make it seem as if you're answering some other question. (The station is *not* in the old town, and I didn't mention *staying* in Tallinn at all.) And yep, I did find out about the walk; if you look, it's actually included in the question (with more details). The Wikitravel taxi advice is good though.

Comment: It was more just if you were wondering about staying as well - I was curious that it appeared you were just zooming straight through.  But if you are going straight to the bus station, then feel free to ignore the old town parts ;)